# Exception in database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website with different instances of the same CMS; they use the same code (PHP), and same database model. Different content of course. I have scripts in place to check for deviations in the database model.

Now, for some of the sites I need to add few extra fields. E.g. all sites have a user table like this (with a corresponding form to fill the data):

```
Table user
  id
  username
  email
```

For a few sites I need to add e.g. address and age, and for another I need to add phone number.

Is there a way to do this without ugly constructions like

```
if ($site_name == 'siteA') {
   /* show field Z */
}
```

Comment: What do you think is ugly with this construction??

Comment: If another site comes and wants to add e.g. age, I have to manually change code. If the site changes name (happens sometimes), I have to manually change code. To me, that's ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an extra table with the site name and the attribute that should be shown for the specific type. For example:

```
 _______________________
| site_name | attribute |
|-----------------------|
| siteA     | address   |
| siteA     | age       |
| siteB     | address   |
| siteB     | phone_no  |
|___________|___________|
```

Store all (basic and extra attributes) in the same table and in your php code generate the select query dynamically by using the information stored in the new table. So, for the above example the query for the first site will be:

```
SELECT id, username, email, address, age FROM user;
```

And for the second one:

```
SELECT id, username, email, address, phone_no FROM user;
```

You can easily create these queries with PHP

Comment: Yes, think that is the most elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use versionning and a technical wrapper class to handle your database accesses.

In the wrapper you would check the version of the database, and according to it perform the appropriate queries.

You could also have a dedicated code, couldn't you? Most likely you have a customer with specific needs. Why not installing him a specific file system?

Comment: For maintenance it is way, way, better to have a single codebase; this is the only exception.

Comment: well it is also way, way better to not have different databases models in that case. I guess you'll have to use the wrapper then, at least it encapsulates the version checks in a single class.

Comment: True, except it's just an extra field in a table. Am looking for a way to keep maintenance easy but also have flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm may help:

Depending on a configuration file and detecting the site name we may do the following:

```
// in conf.php
$siteA_fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field1A');
// in the above array you have to include all fields you want to select with SiteA

$siteB_fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field1B');
// in the above array you have to include all fields you want to select with SiteB

$sites = array('domain1.com' => 'siteA', 'domain2.com' => 'siteB');
```

.

```
// in your script file or master include

function detectDomain(){
 // return domain of the site
}

    function prepareSql(){
    $site = $sites[detectDomain()];
    $fields = $site.'_fields';

    $sql = 'SELECT '.implode(",",$$fields).' FROM table';
    return $sql

    }
```

You are able to improve your prepareSql by adding parameters. This way I think you have not to make such conditional.

**Conclusion:** The solution you need should depends on configuration file.